# Asynchronous loaded jQuery script does not work

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have this scenario.
In my `HTML` page, when click on an `a` element, I load some `HTML` and `jQuery` content as string, and change a `div`'s content (via `innerHTML`) to this new text.

Here is the `jQuery` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.accessor").click(function(event) {
        var cId = this.id;
        $.get("/video/" + cId)
        .done(function(data){
            var contentDiv = document.getElementById("navigator");
            contentDiv.innerHTML = data;
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            alert("An error occured during request. Please try again later!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that after this `jQuery` code runs, the new `jQuery` code (that replace this one), does not respond.

Bellow is the new `HTML/jQuery` code that I get:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <a href="/video">Competitors</a>
    <span>&gt;</span>
    <a href="#">Name</a>
</div>
<div class="video-browser">
    @for(v <- competitor.getVideos()) {
        <div class="folder">
            <a id="@(competitor.getId())_@v.getId()" class="accessor">
                <img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/movie_file.png")" />
                <span>@v.getVideoName()</span>
            </a>
        </div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.accessor").click(function(event) {
        alert(123);
    });
</script>
```

**Obs.** I put some code related to my framework that I use for the sake of conciseness.

Having the `HTML/jQuery` above, when I try to click on an `a` element I get nothing. Can anybody explain me why this?

If you need more details, ask me for, please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks looks like some template language `@for(v <- competitor.getVideos()) {` (no `html`, `js` or `jQuery`) where do you expect this to be processed?

Comment: Why do you expect jQuery to be able to automatically parse your server sided template code?

Comment: Script that is injected into your page as you have done above does not get executed.  You'll need to load it separately.  `$.getScript()` would solve your problem.

Comment: @t.niese The code on client side is correct. I wrote that way to be more concise.

Comment: @Archer using the `append` of jQuery (`$("#navigator").append(data)`) using should also execute it, but you are right `contentDiv.innerHTML = data` would not execute the js code.

Comment: @Archer I think you hit the nail. I'm very new to `jQuery`. Can you dive a little bit please?

Comment: @RichardBanks no error message in console.

Comment: I've added an answer with a modified script for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script to this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.accessor").click(function(event) {
        var cId = this.id;
        $.get("/video/" + cId)
            .done(function(data){
                $("#navigator").html(data);
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                alert("An error occured during request. Please try again later!");
            });
    });
</script>
```

It uses jQuery's `html()` method to add the new html (and script), and this will execute the script, unlike the previous method you used.

Answer (score -1):

this is because your click event handler is not initialized. You need to wrap this in a document ready block. However...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("a.accessor").click(function(event) {
        alert(123);
    });
});
</script>
```

wont work neither because the a tags are not in the DOM. better to use delegation. This will add a click handler to all a tags inside .accessor also when added in the future. Put this code in your main html.

```
$(function(){
    $(".accessor").on('click', 'a',function(event) {
        alert(123);
    });
});
```

Comment: The links are in the html directly above the script.  This has nothing to do with delegation.